# Tesseract OCR fails to recongnize number 7

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

im trying to analyze a picture but tesseract seems to have a problem diferentiating the number 7 from the number 1.

current config:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 7 --oem 1 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

[image: this is the picture in question]

[image: this is the result]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import requests
import io

response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrNIR.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content)), lang='eng',
                    config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

print(text)
```

Output:

```
776
```

You can also use the `tesseract` command to print the result to the standard output:

```
tesseract input.png stdout -l eng --psm 13 --oem 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, sadly it dosent seem to be working as intended, when I run it it just show the number 6, could it be that something is wrong with my import of tesseract? Im currently trying to create an app that screenshots the other app, takes the image and transforms it to text so it can be save as an txt file, I can show you what I got that was almost working but sometimes its still buggy I dont know if its because of my bad implementation of tesseract or if it dosent recognizes the font type

Comment: def send_image():
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    image= cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
     thresh = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    print(data)
    data = wording(data)
    print(data)
    return (data)  //path is my image (the 776 saved in my c drive)

Comment: @Kevin: I am using `tesseract 4.1.1`

Comment: I am using 5.0.0-rc1.20211030
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.5.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5 libzstd/1.4.5
 Found libcurl/7.77.0-DEV Schannel zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.5 libidn2/2.0.4 nghttp2/1.31.0